# MATLAB blockproc does not concatenate results

Tags: matlab

For some reason, using the following code:

```
myimg = rand(30, 30);
myfun = @(block) block.data;
B = blockproc(myimg, [5 5], myfun)
```

blockproc returns B as a 30x30 matrix. This doesn't seem to be consistent with the help text of blockproc which claims that the results of myfun are being concatenated (I also tried myfun as a separate function outputting each block to the command line and it is indeed processing a bunch of 5x5 images). Shouldn't B be a concatenation of 5x5 matrices?

Edit: What I'm trying to achieve: tile the input image into **overlapping** tiles. The suggested thread deals with non-overlapping tiles.

Edit 2: So this is the blockproc help text:

*"B = blockproc(A,[M N],FUN) processes the image A by applying the
    function FUN to each distinct M-by-N block of A and concatenating the
    results into the output matrix B. FUN is a function handle to a
    function that accepts a "block struct" as input and returns a matrix,
    vector, or scalar Y: "*

To me, this sounds such that if FUN is identity, I should get a concatenation of all tiles, (expecially as the text allows the return value of FUN to be a matrix) but maybe there is some other way to interpret the text?

Comment: I'm still unclear as to your desired results. Are you looking for a `5x5x676` matrix, or `5x5x36`, or something else? What sort of concatenation are you looking for?

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to make it clearer. I think it is 5x5x676 (I guess you consider the case without padding. Otherwise it should be 5x5x900). I don't care about the form of concatenation as long as it leaves some efficient way to recover the individual tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
myimg = rand(5, 5);
B=repmat(myimg,6);
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what I want is to extract shifted 5x5 tiles from the input image.

Comment: @JohnSmith in that case the question is a duplicate